# Access columns in a CSV.Row by index

Tags: julia

I have a very large (~120 GB) CSV file with ~100 columns. I want to iterate through the file line by line using `CSV.File` and aggregate certain ranges of columns. However, it appears that there is no `getindex` method for the `CSV.Row` type. Here is a simplified example:

```
using CSV
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame(reshape(1:60, 6, 10)) # column names are x1 through x10
CSV.write("test_data.csv", df)

file = CSV.File("test_data.csv")

row1 = first(file)
row1.x3 # Works fine

# Both of these throw method errors:
row1[4]
row1[4:7]
```

Suppose that for each row I want to sum columns `[1:3; 8:10]` in a variable `a` and sum columns `4:7` in a variable `b`. The final output should be a data frame with columns `a` and `b`. Is there an easy way to do this when iterating through `CSV.Row`s?

Comment: Looks like this is being fixed in https://github.com/JuliaData/CSV.jl/pull/510

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Tables.eachcolumn` from the [Tables.jl](https://github.com/JuliaData/Tables.jl), since `CSV.File` supports the Tables interface. `Tables.eachcolumn` will create an iterator over the columns. Then you can use a combination of `Iterators.take` and `Iterators.drop` to access the desired ranges of columns:

```
using CSV
using Tables
using DataFrames
using Base.Iterators: take
using Base.Iterators: drop


function aggregate_file(path)
    file = CSV.File(path)

    a, b = Int64[], Int64[]
    for row in file
        cols = Tables.eachcolumn(row)

        sum1to3 = sum(take(cols, 3))
        sum8to10 = sum(drop(cols, 7))
        push!(a, sum1to3 + sum8to10)

        sum4to7 = sum(drop(take(cols, 7), 3))
        push!(b, sum4to7)
    end

    DataFrame(a = a, b = b)
end
```

```
julia> aggregate_file("test_data.csv")
6×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a     │ b     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 168   │ 112   │
│ 2   │ 174   │ 116   │
│ 3   │ 180   │ 120   │
│ 4   │ 186   │ 124   │
│ 5   │ 192   │ 128   │
│ 6   │ 198   │ 132   │
```

If you need to aggregate over an arbitrary set of column indices, you could use `enumerate` on the column iterator:

```
inds = [2, 4, 7]
sum(j for (i, j) in enumerate(cols) if i in inds)
```

EDIT:

I did a performance comparison of mine and @IanFiske's answer. His version appears to be faster and use less memory:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime aggregate_file("test_data.csv");
  118.687 μs (550 allocations: 24.42 KiB)

julia> @btime aggregate_file("test_data.csv", [1:3; 8:10], 4:7);
  62.416 μs (236 allocations: 14.48 KiB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that lets you avoid having to think about translating to the "drop"/"take" logic:

```
using CSV, Tables, DataFrames

df = DataFrame(reshape(1:60, 6, 10)) # column names are x1 through x10
CSV.write("test_data.csv", df)

function aggregate_file(path, a_inds, b_inds)
    file = CSV.File(path)

    a, b = Int64[], Int64[]
    a_cols = propertynames(file)[a_inds]
    b_cols = propertynames(file)[b_inds]

    for row in file
        push!(a, sum(getproperty.(Ref(row), a_cols)))
        push!(b, sum(getproperty.(Ref(row), b_cols)))
    end

    DataFrame(a = a, b = b)
end
```

```
julia> aggregate_file("test_data.csv", [1:3; 8:10], 4:7)
6×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a     │ b     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 168   │ 112   │
│ 2   │ 174   │ 116   │
│ 3   │ 180   │ 120   │
│ 4   │ 186   │ 124   │
│ 5   │ 192   │ 128   │
│ 6   │ 198   │ 132   │
```

Comment: Thanks. If only I could use index notation on a row... the syntax would be much nicer. Maybe I'll file an issue on CSV.jl and see what the maintainers think. :)

Comment: Btw, `[1:3; 8:10]` works just fine, no need to unpack the ranges into `vcat` like in `[1:3...; 8:10...]`.

Comment: Cool!  You might file that issue with Tables.jl instead of CSV so that `getindex` would work with any data structure conforming to the Tables interface.